# Partition and Consumer location after rebalnce of Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to achieve the following effect.
Let's say I have 9 partitions spread out over 3 workers. that would look something like this:

[image: Before repartition]

What I want to do, is that when a new machine joins the consumer group.
thus adding a new consumer. I want the rebalancing to only move as few partitions as possible to the new consumer.

Like so: 
See how partition 3 6 9 ended up on the new consumer.
While the other consumers retained most of their existing partitions.

[image: After repartition]

Is this possible?
What I want to do is to build stateful systems behind Kafka.
Which I can already do, but when a consumer joins or leaves, the default behavior is just to disconnect everything and then do a rebalance from scratch.
Thus making a lot of partitions to change consumers.
Does any of this make sense?

Comment: There is a proposal for this feature already: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-54+-+Sticky+Partition+Assignment+Strategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, Kafka does not support such feature to do a minimum-impact rebalance or a partial rebalance. However, you can try to implement your own partitioner logic to achieve this by creating a new class which extends o.a.k.clients.consumer.AbstractPartitionAssignor and setting 'partition.assignment.strategy' to its path.

Comment: There is a proposal for this feature already: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-54+-+Sticky+Partition+Assignment+Strategy

Comment: The comment from @MatthiasJ.Sax is exactly what I was after :)